# node js — write after end

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm stuck with an error message, i.e., `write` is called after `end`. My `app.js` looks like this:

```
var router = require('./router.js');

// Create a web server
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  router.home(request, response);
  router.valuation(request, response);

}).listen(3000);
console.log('Server running.');
```

The relevant part of the `router.js` looks like this.

```
// Handle ticker valuation 
  function valuation(request, response) {

  var ticker = request.url.replace('/valuation/','');
  if (request.url === '/valuation/' + ticker) {

    if(ticker.length > 0) {
      response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      response.write('Header\n');
      scraper.roe(ticker, response);
      scraper.roic(ticker, response);
      response.end('Footer\n');

    }
  };

  // on 'error', show error

  //response.end('Error');
};
```

The relevant part of the `scraper.js` file that utilizes the `xray` module and features the functions roe and roic looks like this:

```
//Get ROIC
function roic(ticker, response) {

    x('http://www.example.com/' + ticker + '/ROIC/', 'table.R10', [{

        table: x('td', [{
            date: x('tr:first-child td', 'strong'),
            roic: x('tr:nth-child(2) td', 'strong')

        }])


    }])(function(err, obj) {

        //Display only the first table, i.e. annual data. Slice quarterly data.
        obj = obj.slice(0, 1);
        obj = obj[0].table;

        response.write('On ' + obj[0].date + ' ' + ticker + '\'s ' + 'ROIC was ' + obj[10].roic + '\n');

        //response.end('Footer\n');

    })
};


//Get ROE
function roe(ticker, response) {

    x('http://www.example.com/' + ticker + '/ROE/', 'table.R10', [{

        table: x('td', [{
            date: x('tr:first-child td', 'strong'),
            roe: x('tr:nth-child(2) td', 'strong')

        }])


    }])(function(err, obj) {

        //Display only the first table, i.e. annual data. Slice quarterly data.
        obj = obj.slice(0, 1);
        obj = obj[0].table;

        response.write('On ' + obj[0].date + ' ' + ticker + '\'s ' + 'ROE was ' + obj[10].roe + '\n');

        //response.end('Footer\n');

    })


};
```

The console logs, if included, appropriately the `obj`, but I don't see the output in the browser, because it returns the common error mentioned above. Additionally, if I were to uncomment the `response.end('Footer\n')` part in either the `roe` or `roic` function, the output would work, but only for one function and not both or more.

I am quite inexperienced and therefore would be happy if someone could propose a structural change in the code that would allow me to run multiple scraper functions—besides the `scraper.roe()` and `scraper.roic()` function—and just after competition run the `response.end()` in the `router.js` file.

I am aware of the `.on('end', fn() {})` method but could not implement it properly.

Comment: It looks to me like you're looking for something to help out with flow control. Have you looked into using Promises or async?

Comment: @ruquay Thanks man. I tried wit `async`'s `series` method but still get the same error, i.e., write after end.

Comment: What is `x`? Does it cause `response.write` to be called asynchronously? If so, then that would explain the error, since you're calling `response.end` synchronously. I agree with ruquay: you need async or similar. You say you've tried this, but you haven't said exactly what you've done. `roe` and `roic` should each accept a callback function as an argument, and they should call the callback function after `response.write` (asynchronously). Then `async.parallel([async.apply(scraper.roe, ticker, response), async.apply(scraper.roic, ticker, response)], function() { response.end("Footer\n"); });`.

Comment: @DavidKnipe `x` denotes the use of the `x-ray`module: [link](https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray). Thank you for your approach, I tried it and the `response.end('Footer\n')` callback never gets triggered for some reason—. Please excuse if some of my statements are vague, but I am just a beginner. So thank you for your patience.

Comment: What change did you make to `roe` and `roic`? It should be `function roic(ticker, response, callback) { x(...)(function(err, obj) { if (err) { callback(err); } else { ... callback(null); } }); }` (and similarly for `roe`). Is this what you did? If you do `console.log` inside the `function(err, obj)` functions, do you see the log? PS: My previous answer didn't include error handling in the final callback because I ran out of characters :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
 scraper.roe(ticker, response);
 scraper.roic(ticker, response);
 response.end('Footer\n');
```

is executed synchronously, but each call to scraper does asynchronous calls to external ressources before calling `response.write`.

So `response.end` is indeed always called too early.

Note that you also currently have no way to know which result (roe or roic) will come first.

In order to orchestrate the calls, you will need to modify your roe and roic functions so that they call a callback with their result + use https://github.com/caolan/async#paralleltasks-callback

Comment: what do you suggest? How can I wait for the callbacks of each function and execute the `response.end` after all callbacks are received?